# Can two SQL statements in same DB transaction reference other's updated field?

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions, mariadb

If I UPDATE and then INSERT in a database transaction (mariadb InnoDB), can the INSERT statement reference the timestamp field of the UPDATEed record and get the UPDATEed value?

Meaning, will the effects of an UPDATE be seen by subsequent statements in the same transaction?

Comment: An example query would help considerably here. Your phrasing is ambiguous as to which record you're talking about.

Comment: Yes.  Within the transaction the new data should be seen.  Outside the transaction, it should not be seen.

Comment: You say 'data' but what about an 'on update CURRENT TIMESTAMP' timestamp field?